# How to change the thumbnail images along with the base image of configurable products?

Tags: magento-1.9, color-swatches

When I click on color swatches in product details page only the respective base image is changing . I want to the related set of thumbnail images also to change with respective to the selected swatch.

> Note: I do not want to use any extension.

Please help.

Comment: then how do you want to do it, if you don't want an extension ?

Comment: I want it to do it by editing my code. Kindly help me if that is possible.

Comment: this means you need an extension. Either you create one or build one.

Comment: Okay suggest one extension.

Comment: https://github.com/tzyganu/Switcher. But for 1.9 you have to disable the color swatches functionality.  Docs on how it works and how to configure, can be found here: https://github.com/tzyganu/Switcher/wiki